# I am facing a problem i have duplicates in array list with same objects when i make changes in one duplicate object it updates others as well

Tags: android, arraylist, singleton

i am using singleton class to add data from activity and then get the arralist in fragments to add to cart function when i update the quantity by position based it updates the other duplicates quantity as well

**MODEL CLASS**

public class UTIL  {

public static   List productModels ;

```
public  static  List<ProductModel> getModel()
{
    if(productModels==null)
    {
        productModels = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return productModels;
}

public  static void setModel(ProductModel productModel)
{
   if(productModels==null)
   {
       productModels = new ArrayList<>();
    productModels.add(productModel);
   }
   else {
       productModels.add(productModel);
   }

}
public  static void replace(List<ProductModel> productModel)
{
    if(productModels==null)
    {
        productModels = productModel;
    }
    else {
        productModels=productModel;
    }


}
```

}

**MAKING CHANGES**

UTIL.getModel().get(0).setNumberofitem("!");

now if i update index 0 it also updates the other duplicates objects in it

Comment: Can you formulate a clear question?

Comment: yes the problem is  UTIL.setModel(productModels.get(viewPager2.getCurrentItem()));
 i am passing the object like this to the singleton class to add the obkect into the list present in the singleton class so when i add duplicates means when i pass same object into the singleton class already stored there it add it to the arralist in the singleton but when i make changes to the one of the dublicates it automatically update the other present dublicates in that arralyist without even modifying it that is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does it mean "duplicates"?. The same object? If I understand right, your list contains a few links to the same object.

Comment: so, it's a normal behavior. You change this object and the list contains a few links to the object.

Comment: When you put object to the list, doesn't matter in what index, the list doesnt't copy the object. So you have the same object in different index.

Comment: so what should i do that if i make changes in index 1 it does effect the other

Comment: yes i fixed this problem by creating a temp new object and then passing it so it will create new object instead of coping

Comment: you can add some id to your object to make your objects different.